# Ajax events for primefaces components

Tags: jsf, primefaces

How can I know the  ajax events for every primefaces components like piechart etc ? Is a list available somewhere?

Comment: possible duplicate of [List of <p:ajax> events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586779/list-of-pajax-events)

Comment: I don't think any availability of document which showing component & its Ajax Event only. The recommended way is to go through PrimeFaces User Guide for your PrimeFaces version and then iterate through each component and its Ajax Event.

In PrimeFaces User Guide they have specified Ajax Behavior Events related to each component.