# list of `<p:selectOneMenu>` event

Tags: ajax, events, jsf-2, primefaces, selectonemenu

I would like to have the entire list of `<p:selectoneMenu>` event.
I know that, when using `<p:ajax>` the default event is `change`.

Thanks.

Comment: What you have tried??

Comment: I want to handle the event when the user select a value of `<p:selectOneMenu>` even if that value doesn't change (same value before clicking on it).

Answer (score 1):

Basically, `<p:selectOneMenu>` renders a [html `<ul>` tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ul.asp) at client side. Being it a non-form tag, you can consider [every single event](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp) which can happen on it (also form events, as the generated output should be inside a form) to use in your ajax firing. That implies keyboard or mouse events for example.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11587064/1199132) and what Primefaces lead [Cagatay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/306753/cagatay-civici) says about that:

> Non-custom events like, click, keyup are not documented as it is general knowledge of dom events.

So, if the component has a customized event, it is actually documented in the [guide](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html). If not, just check the general dom events.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<p:selectOneMenu 
valueChangeListener="#{...}" onchange="submit()"
```