# How to set global="false" on primefaces datatable pagination buttons and select

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I've been struggling to set `global="false"` as the attribute of **ajax** on **primefaces** that makes `ajaxStatus` skips this component, however I've handled column filtering event and resize,reorder also sorting, Yet couldn't find any suitable ajax event name to set global to false for datatable pagination buttons/selects events.

On the primefaces datatable

```
paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
```

Filter **reorder**, **resize**, **filter** and **sort** events :

```
<p:ajax event="colReorder" listener="#{dyna.onColumnReorder}" global="false" />-->
<p:ajax event="colResize" listener="#{dyna.onColumnResize}" update=":center_form:tabexam" global="false"/> 
<p:ajax event="filter"  global="false"/>
<p:ajax event="sort"  global="false"/>
```

What i need now is the pagination event name, i hope that i made my self clear, also a link to all primefaces ajax event names, would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can find here most of the events lists:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586779/list-of-pajax-events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done.

Using :

```
<p:ajax event="page" global="false"/>
```

Comment: although still looking for a good link for all ajax event names.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is an event for pagination.

Refer to : http://www.primefaces.org/documentation  download which ever version but there is a section called Ajax Behaviour Events - page 154 in 4.0.

Page 134 shows all the attributes you can set on the p:datatable