# Trigger valueChange event after a visible character is added or removed in InputText

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am in need for a `valueChange` event, that triggers every time a visible character is added or removed.

I've got 2 inputText-fields, one of which is read only and a commandButton.

```
<div>
  <p:inputText>
    <p:ajax id="encodedString" event="valueChange"/>
  </p:inputText>

  <p:commandButton action="#{bean.foo}" update="output"/>

  <p:inputText id="output" readonly="true">
  </p:inputText>
</div>
```

Now, the users enters some encoded string in the first field and presses the button, which then decodes the string and presents it in human readable form in the read-only input field. Now, whenever the user manipulates the original string, the output should be reset since it does not represent the original encoded string anymore.

Sadly, the `valueChange` event only triggers when the input field loses focus. I have tried the `keypress` event, but it also triggers when buttons like the arrow keys are pressed.

JavaScript is viable for me, but should be omitted if possible.

What is the best way to trigger the `valueChange` event (or a similar event) whenever the **actual** input changes? I.e. when a visible character is added or removed.

Comment: JSF typically uses the default JavaScript events to trigger AJAX. I don't know about a javascript event that is triggered every time the text field content ist altered. I think a bit of javascript will be necessary.

Comment: i feel like this comment is not that helpful to this post but i also dont want to ignore it. thanks for caring for my question :)

Comment: Javascript's [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) event should suit your needs.

Comment: inputText has a keydown event too, use that one dude

Comment: your question at the end is answered: just use keydown event to make sure it always gets the changes on the inputtext

Comment: @bugsforbreakfast: 'dude'  is not the best word to use. You can even just leave it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You essentially need the HTML DOM [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) event. This relatively new event is unfortunately [not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586779/list-of-pajax-events) in `<p:ajax>` of `<p:inputText>` because the `oninput` attribute is [not supported](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/7.0/primefaces-p/inputText.html) in `<p:inputText>` (yet?).

However, you can make use of [JSF 2.2's passthrough attributes feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666472/custom-html-tag-attributes-are-not-rendered-by-jsf) to force JSF to render an `oninput` attribute anyway where you in turn explicitly trigger the default `onchange()` function.

```
<... xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">

<p:inputText value="#{bean.value}" a:oninput="onchange()">
    <p:ajax listener="#{bean.listener}" />
</p:inputText>
```

True, that involves JavaScript but it's really only a small bit.

Note that I removed `event="valueChange"` from `<p:ajax>` because that's [the default one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886453/what-values-can-i-pass-to-the-event-attribute-of-the-fajax-tag/) already.

Answer (score -3):

value changed event not supported for  inputText  you have to  use 
 keyup or blur

```
<p:inputText>
    <p:ajax id="encodedString" event="keyup"/>
  </p:inputText>
```

Comment: Nope. OP don't want to trigger ajax when e.g. arrow buttons are pressed.